How to setup BALKAN FamilyTreeJS in NextJS 14
I'm trying to integrate the @balkangraph/familytree.js package into my Next.js (App router, v14) project, but I'm encountering several issues with my configuration (following the docs).
Specifically, I'm running into errors related to the usage of require in next.config.js, as well as Tailwind CSS configuration issues (after following the docs guide).
I've followed the package's documentation but couldn't find any specific tutorials or examples for Next.js setups.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Next.js Configuration as per the docs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
import nextTranspileModules from "next-transpile-modules";
const withTM = nextTranspileModules(["@balkangraph/familytree.js"]);

const nextConfig = {};

export default withTM(nextConfig);

However, this throws an error when I attempt to run the app:
Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Issues Encountered:

Require in next.config.js:

Initially, using require caused an error because it's not supported in ES module scope. I switched to ES6 import, but the same errors persisted.


Tailwind CSS issue:

When using Tailwind CSS, I'm encountering errors when trying to transpile the @balkangraph/familytree.js module alongside Tailwind.



Here's a screenshot of the errors I'm seeing:

Tailwind issue: 

Here's the closest I've gotten in the installation:



Question:
Has anyone successfully set up @balkangraph/familytree.js in a Next.js project with Tailwind CSS? What specific configuration changes do I need to make to resolve the errors? Is there a better approach to handle module transpilation alongside other configurations like Tailwind in Next.js?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

The usage of "next-transpile-modules" is deprecated for next14. Can you try the migration guide and then say if it solves the problem?

thanks @visualVim, I just tried to change it to the following (see img if it's correct).
https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/e71dcfd6-126d-4bf5-9f97-ab2a003793c7
No error, but it's still blank.
Here's the repo for closer look: https://github.com/unclebay143/famnode

It's blank but it's loading correctly(inspect html and see). Might be some miss configuration..

I've tried over again with different config examples, and it's the same thing.

Currently there is an issue with the NPM version of the product. You can try to use the downloaded version from here: https://balkan.app/FamilyTreeJS/Download

thanks @Zorry, downloaded version works now (wasn't working for me previously)

There was a issue with the installation package. It is fixed now. Please try again.

Thanks for the help. I've tried removing the package and installing it back, but didn't work. pnpm add @balkangraph/familytree.js
Let me know if I'm missing something.
(currently using the downloaded version for now)

It should work now.

just tested it, it works now! Thanks for taking a look and getting back
